# From Bali to Jakarta by bus and ferry how to?

Tags: buses, ferries, bali, jakarta

How to get from Bali to Jakarta by bus and ferry?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Ubung bus terminal, catch a bus to Gilimanuk, cross by ferry to Banyuwangi (Ketapang), continue to Surabaya, take long-distance bus across Java to Jakarta.  This will take *at least* 24 hours, much of it on bad roads with suicidal bus drivers hopped up on drugs.  Most travel agencies can organize a through ticket for you, or you can try to find your own way - it's not particularly hard, but scammers will do their best to make you overpay.

A *much* better alternative is to fly.  This covers the distance in an hour and half, is about the same price if you book in advance with a low-cost carrier like Air Asia, and is far more comfortable and safe.

Comment: I once took a bus on the route Bali - Jakarta, but only from Probolinggo to Jakarta and that alone took 26 hours. I can only agree with this answer, it is a very long trip and the roads are anything but safe. Another thing to consider is where the bus will drop you off in Jakarta. Mine dropped me off in some outskirt area at the bus company depot (and not a bus terminal) and it was pretty hard to get to where I wanted to as I didn't know where was. So if you want to do this trip, do make sure you know where the bus is going to drop you off.